# Function's limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $h(x) = x^2$ if $x \in \mathbb Q$ and $h(x) = x^3$ otherwise.

What is $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$? What is $\lim_{x \to 1} h(x)$? If a is not equal to 0 and a is not equal to 1, show that $\lim_{x \to a} h(x)$ does not exist.

Would the limit be 0 when x goes to 0 and 1 when x goes to 1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the continuous functions $x\mapsto x^2$ and $x\mapsto x^3$ share the fixed points $0$ and $1$.

Comment: So, $\lim_{x \to 0} h(x)$ = 0 and $\lim_{x \to 1} h(x)$ = 1? And since they share fixed points 0 and 1, when a is not equal to 0 or 1 then the limit does not exist?

Comment: Write $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x^3$. Then by continuity, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=g(0)=0$. Also by continuity, $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=f(1)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}g(x)=g(1)=1$. Since $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=0$, we must have $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)=0$. Similarly for $x\to 1$.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist anywhere else because the functions share no other common values.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot! :)